# Session dies in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, apache2

I have an app built in CI and I would like that sessions don't die unless users close their browser. In my config file I have the following:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 0;
```

But session still dies after a period of time, is there any other configuration I need to do? Maybe directly on the server that might be causing the session to die? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

by default, PHP sessions are garbage collected after 24 minutes.

Comment: CI doesn't use native PHP sessions

Comment: Thanks @Frank Farmer I changed the garbage collection time to see how that works, plus I added a function to run periodically and see if that keeps the session alive.